# Jgit - How to filter big files clone

Tags: java, jgit, git-lfs

I'm trying to clone a repository that contains one big file (above 2GB),
As this [article](https://tickets.dominodatalab.com/hc/en-us/articles/360058040352-Critical-Error-Object-too-large-rejecting-the-pack-Max-object-size-limit-is-2-147-483-639-bytes-#:%7E:text=Jgit%20has%20a%20pack%20size,past%20commits%20to%20the%20repo.) mentions the max size of a file Jgit can handle is 2GB.
I saw that through pure git command I can filter big files using `git clone --filter=blob:limit=100m`
And now I want to implement this filter in my java code that uses Jgit so I would be able to avoid the exception
`Object too large (2,424,185,920 bytes), rejecting the pack. Max object size limit is 2,147,483,639`
Currently I do the cloning using Jgit like this :

```
Git  git = Git.cloneRepository()
                        .setURI(gitUrl)
                        .setBranch(branch)
                        .setCloneAllBranches(false)
                        .setCredentialsProvider(credentialsProvider)
                        .setDirectory(directory)
                        .call();
```

I wonder if there is option to add filter to the clone so it will avoid cloning big files using Jgit?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could use InMemoryRepository, and then RevWalk/TreeWalk to filter based on size.

https://github.com/centic9/jgit-cookbook/blob/master/src/main/java/org/dstadler/jgit/porcelain/CloneRemoteRepositoryIntoMemoryAndReadFile.java

The example below is a copy of jgit-cookbook:

```
 public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, GitAPIException {
        DfsRepositoryDescription repoDesc = new DfsRepositoryDescription();
        InMemoryRepository repo = new InMemoryRepository(repoDesc);
        Git git = new Git(repo);
        git.fetch()
                .setRemote(REMOTE_URL)
                .setRefSpecs(new RefSpec("+refs/heads/*:refs/heads/*"))
                .call();
        repo.getObjectDatabase();
        ObjectId lastCommitId = repo.resolve("refs/heads/" + BRANCH);
        RevWalk revWalk = new RevWalk(repo);
        RevCommit commit = revWalk.parseCommit(lastCommitId);
        RevTree tree = commit.getTree();
        TreeWalk treeWalk = new TreeWalk(repo);
        treeWalk.addTree(tree);
        treeWalk.setRecursive(true);
        treeWalk.setFilter(PathFilter.create(FILE_TO_READ));
        if (!treeWalk.next()) {
            return;
        }
        ObjectId objectId = treeWalk.getObjectId(0);
        ObjectLoader loader = repo.open(objectId);
        loader.copyTo(System.out);
    }
```

Please note that I have not tried to filter by file size specifically, however you could investigate TreeWalk

Comment: In this case the filter is by file name, what should be the case to filter by size?